# Predicting midprice of FX pair increases in exchange Y if it increases in exchange X

Tags: market-microstructure, market-making

I want to make a predictive model to see if the mid-price of *P* (FX Pair) increases in Exchange *X* that *P* will increase in Exchange *Y* within *n* seconds with a certain statistical confidence.

Exchange *X* has the most trading volume for *P* and Exchange *Y* has a much lower volume.

I am using simple returns to make them the same unit in case I want to predict two different FX pairs.

My data looks like this

```
Time, X, Y
00:00:00, 1%, 0%
00:00:01, 0%, 1%
00:00:02, 2%, 0%
00:00:03, 0%, 2%
```

You can visually see that there's a 1 second delay 
I am interested to know what literature there is that have tackled this problem?